# CSS tables: colspan row to full table width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-tables

I have a set of nested blocks with `display: table-*` rules. They compose a fluid table (I need to not set specific `width` sizes).

How can I add a row that *colspans* the whole table width?
(**note:** the row is between other rows; not at the top neither at the bottom)

I found a solution, relying on JS, where I calculate the difference (in *px*) between the whole width and the width of row (dependant on the content), and use it as `margin-right`.

See [this example](http://codepen.io/Pictor13/pen/aNgZdW)

But it doesn't calculate the sizes correctly (if you check the web-inspector sizes, compared to the ones in the `console.log`, you see the discrepancy).

Is it possible to colspan the row to the whole table width?
What are other solutions/technics? (because this has the disadvantage of having to recalculate each time that the browser window is resized).

Comment: Only HTML tables have colspan. CSS 2.1 tables allows multiple colspan but does not provide any way to specify it. Probably CSS Tables Level 3 will introduce `column-span` in tables.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I am aware of that. Maybe my question is not clear enough; I am looking for ways to simulate a *colspan*, and am wondering what technics are available (using only CSS, or with the help of JS).

Answer (score 0):

There are no real ways to do this, so it depends how far from your currently layout you feel comfortable going.

In this version each "row" is seen as a table, so it doesn't matter how many cells you put in each.

```css
.table-row {
  display: table;
  width: 50%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  background: #ccc;
}
.title {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px;
}
.colspan {
  background-color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-row">
  <div class="cell title">1</div>
  <div class="cell title">2</div>
  <div class="cell title">3</div>
  <div class="cell title">4</div>
</div>
<div class="table-row">
  <div class="cell">content 1</div>
  <div class="cell">content 2</div>
  <div class="cell">content 3</div>
  <div class="cell">content 4</div>
</div>
<div class="table-row">
  <div class="cell colspan">how-do-I-make-this-colspan-the-whole-width-of-the-table-row?</div>
</div>
<div class="table-row">
  <div class="cell">content 1</div>
  <div class="cell">content 2</div>
  <div class="cell">content 3</div>
  <div class="cell">content 4</div>
</div>
```

It's also relatively easy to style too

```css
.table-row {
  display: table;
  width: 50%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  background: #ccc;
  border-top: 1px solid #000
}
.table-row:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  color: #111;
}
.cell:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #000
}
.title {
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #ccc;
}
.colspan {
  background-color: #32cd32
}
```

```html
<div class="table-row">
  <div class="cell title">1</div>
  <div class="cell title">2</div>
  <div class="cell title">3</div>
  <div class="cell title">4</div>
</div>
<div class="table-row">
  <div class="cell">content 1</div>
  <div class="cell">content 2</div>
  <div class="cell">content 3</div>
  <div class="cell">content 4</div>
</div>
<div class="table-row">
  <div class="cell colspan">how-do-I-make-this-colspan-the-whole-width-of-the-table-row?</div>
</div>
<div class="table-row">
  <div class="cell">content 1</div>
  <div class="cell">content 2</div>
  <div class="cell">content 3</div>
  <div class="cell">content 4</div>
</div>
```